# Login page code enhancement

Tags: c#, beginner, .net, asp.net, authentication

I am starting to learn ASP.NET, and I am designing a page for an admin to login and do some stuff. I have the username and password for the admin stored in Web.config (Is that a good practice?).

Second thing, I am checking if the user filled the username and password fields, then I am checking if the values for the admin and password exist in the web.config, then I am checking if these values equal each other, so I am having 3 nested if. Is that a good practice as well?

Here's my code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLoginId.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text))
            {
                string configLoginID = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminLoginID"];
                string configPassword = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPassword"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configLoginID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(configPassword))
                {
                    if (txtLoginId.Text == configLoginID && txtPassword.Text == configPassword)
                    {
                        Session["ShoppingAdmin"] = "ShoppingAdmin";
                        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/AddNewProducts.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblAlert.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password";
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblAlert.Text = "Please enter a usernamd and password";
            }
```

Last thing, checking empty fields using `!string.IsNullOrEmpty` for each field, is that the right thing to do?

I would like to write a clean code, thanks for helping me with these 3 cases.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing webforms and not MVC?

Comment: I haven't worked with any of them before, so I wanted to do a project on ASP.NET first, then try to do it in MVC5. I thought this way I will be learning everything. Is that right?

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  In future questions, you may want to post more of your code.  We do not require minimal examples.  Unless your program is large, you can post the whole thing.

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford "MVC is the future", in a way, and you need to be careful not to pick up bad habits from starting with WebForms. See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/224553/123339 (but do read the other answers too).

Comment: @mdfst13 thanks a lot. But this is the only code I have so far, nothing else. It's just a login page and that's its code.

Comment: @BCdotWEB wouldn't it help to know the principles of ASP.NET first before going into MVC? I've never used ADO.NET or gridviews etc.. Any tip?

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford It depends on what your job requires, but quite frankly these days chances are you'd be better off learning MVC or WebAPI + AngularJS, and ORMs like Entity Framework instead of ADO.NET. Look for instance at the "Specializing In One Area" section of this: http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/2013/05/17/net-developer-career-advice-getting-started-later-in-life/ and note how WebForms aren't even mentioned.

Comment: @Brittany As a long time developer in all the Microsoft stacks Im just chiming in with BCdotWEB. Learning the horrifics of asp.net is just learning bad habits. Go directly to mvc.net. Then add some Entity Framework knowhow to that. THEN decide in what direction you want to further your knowledge. Good luck!

Comment: @BCdotWEB please add your comment as an answer, thank you for the great guidance :)

Comment: @BCdotWEB The last company I worked for exclusively used Web Forms, so your recommendation to focus only on MVC or WebAPI is invalid. In fact, we couldn't use MVC for our system, as the underlying technology wouldn't allow it.

Comment: @EBrown Quite frankly, you should not work for such companies. Also, "the underlying technology wouldn't allow it" sounds like massive BS to me.

Comment: @BCdotWEB The technology we used was an AS/400 on DB2 for all of our data, it basically required a roll-you-own ADO.NET implementation, which wouldn't very well fit with MVC. And "you should not work for such companies" is a BS argument: 1. you don't always have a choice, 2. there's nothing wrong with Web Forms. People just get a bad stigma from it because it's "too similar to PHP and other 'outdated' technologies." Personally, I find Web Forms to be much more appropriate for a great deal many tasks, which would be overcomplicated by MVC.

Answer (score 2):

> I have the username and password for the admin stored in Web.config (Is that a good practice?).

No, it's not good practice to store the Admin login (or any login, for that matter) in the Web.config.

Depending on what ASP.NET model you're using, you have a few options. MVC has a built-in `Roles` provider which makes it simple to make certain pages/areas only accessible by  a specific role.

Web Forms is also pretty simple, though you have to roll your own access provisions. You can use the built-in Simple Membership if you like, which usually suits quite well once extended to fit your needs. (You can add properties to users pretty easily and such.)

You also aren't encrypting or hashing the password, which is a huge no-no. At the very least you should MD5 hash it, though for security I would recommend SHA1-salt hashing at the very weakest. Though, if you use the built-in Simple Membership for Web Forms or MVC, you'll get encryption and salting by default.

I didn't review the *actual code* as Heslacher did that just fine, but I do think you need to completely revisit the login system. ASP.NET has built-in providers for this, and they're super easy and, quite honestly, pretty fun to set up. (I don't know why no one has pointed this out in the several months this question has been here, or how it got on my radar, but hopefully you still get this advice.)

Answer (score 1):

Using a guard condtion by switching the conditions of the outer `if` condition you can return early and its more obvious what is hapening like so

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLoginId.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPassword.Text))
{ 
    lblAlert.Text = "Please enter a username and password";
    return;
}
```

The same can be done for the next `if` condition like so

```
string configLoginID = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminLoginID"];
string configPassword = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPassword"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configLoginID) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(configPassword))
{
    return;
}
```

leaving the remaining `if..else` like so

```
if (txtLoginId.Text == configLoginID && txtPassword.Text == configPassword)
{
    Session["ShoppingAdmin"] = "ShoppingAdmin";
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin/AddNewProducts.aspx");
}
else
{
    lblAlert.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password";
}
```

Doing is this way will reduce the nesting hence reduces the horizontal spacing which makes the code more readable.